# Lisp - prime number

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, primes, primality-test

I am trying to learn lisp and I have some difficulties with prime numbers. I need a function `is-prime` and if it is prime I have to return `t` and if it is not I have to return `nil`.

```
(prime 41) => t

(prime 35) => nil
```

So far I've got:

```
(defun is-prime (n d) 
  (if (= d 1) 
      (print "t") 
      (if (= (% n d) 0) 
          (print "nil") 
          (is-prime (n (- d 1) )))))
```

but I have 2 parameters there and I have no idea how to use only one. Plus, it's not working at all. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have few missteps there:

```
(defun is-prime (n d) 
  (if (= d 1) 
      (print "t") 
      (if (= (% n d) 0) 
          (print "nil")
```

First of all, don't `print` your results, just return them.  Second, there's no `%` function, it's `rem`.

The real error is how you make the recursive call. You have an extra pair of parentheses there:

```
          (is-prime (n (- d 1) )))))
          ;         ^          ^
          ;        this      and this
```

in Lisp, parentheses signify a function call; but you don't intend to call `n` with an argument `(- d 1)`, they both are arguments to `is-prime`. So we just need to remove those extra parentheses,

```
          (is-prime  n (- d 1)  ))))
```

So what does it do? It counts down: `d`, `(- d 1)` ... `1`. And when `(= d 1)`, it returns `t`. So, one way to call it is

```
(defun is-prime (n &optional (d (- n 1))) 
  (or (= d 1)
      (and (/= (rem n d) 0)
           (is-prime  n (- d 1)))))
```

but it is not the most efficient way, :) nor the most *safe* one, either.

It is much better to count up, not down, for one thing, because any random number is far more likely to have a smaller factor than a larger one. Then, it lets us optimize where we *stop* -- and stopping at the `sqrt` is much *much* more efficient, and just as correct.

Comment: This looks slick. Could you comment on the recursion and parameter passing? Does the function call itself while passing subsequently decreasing second parameter each time?

Comment: @ArtforLife *"Does the function call itself while passing subsequently decreasing second parameter each time?"* yes. Not all the time, just if it needs to do so -- i.e. if `d` wasn't `1` (when `T` is returned), and `(rem n d)` wasn't `0` (when `NIL` is returned).

Comment: I see. It seems that the function breaks when called with argument 1. It gives division by zero.

Comment: @ArtforLife right. :) that's what I hint at, with "not ... the most safe [way to call this function]". :)

Comment: Got it. So some checking is in order in the beginning? Also, one can optimize by only checking `d = isqrt(n)` and below.

Comment: @ArtforLife yes indeed; only in the reverse order, from 2 and up, optimizing "where we *stop*".

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're halfway there.

Here's my explanation in English:

You have written in lisp a function is-prime (btw, "yes or no" functions like that are usually named whatever-p in lisp) that tells you if n is *relatively* prime to d.

What you need to do is go through all d's less than n, and if it's *not* relatively prime to any of them, return *nil*, but if after that loop you haven't returned *nil*, then return *t*. Your friend here is the function "mod", which tells you whether there is a remainder when its first argument is divided by its second.

Something like:

```
(defun primep (n)
 (cond
  ((= 1    n)          nil)
   (t
   (loop
     :with root     = (isqrt n)
     :with divisors = (loop :for i :from 3 :to root :by 2 :collect i)
     :for d = (pop divisors)
     :if (zerop (mod n d))
     :do (return nil)
     :else :do (setf divisors (delete-if (lambda (x) (zerop (mod x d))) divisors))
     :while divisors
     :finally (return t)))))
```

Also, don't print nil, just return nil.

Comment: I see what are you doing here but I was trying to make it recursive. How can I make it recursive and keep only one parameter n ?

Comment: Possibly, but this isn't a candidate for tail recursion, so there's not a good reason to make it recursive (Lisp is a lot more than just recursive functions...). Let me see what I can knock together...

Answer (score 1):

I have taken Will Ness's answer as an inspiration and modified the function. Here is the code. Is checks whether 1 is passed as a parameter and makes sure to output `nil` should that be the case.

```
(defun is-prime (n &optional (d (- n 1))) 
  (if (/= n 1) (or (= d 1)
      (and (/= (rem n d) 0)
           (is-prime  n (- d 1)))) ()))
```

I am still learning Common Lisp, so if there are problems with this, please let me know.

Comment: it is much better to count up from 2 to sqrt(n) (inclusive), instead of counting down from (n-1) to 2. also, Common Lisp doesn't like recursion; your intent is a loop so better write it down as a loop. With `loop`, or `do`, or `prog` even. as for your code, you are still not handling cases where `(< n 1)`.